# how to define the lastest time of publication for a time series

Tags: sql, sas

I have a hundred time series.

These time series are among a hundred of thousand of other time series published by a major european institution, either at the end of each quarter or at the end of each month.

The institution does not publish the release date for the time series because it is too cumbersome. They publish, however, the timeliness for each series.

To have the estimate release date for the time series, you need to have the end of the quarters or the end of the months and you add a certain numbers of days to it.

An example would be

```
Serie A: Q1 2014 = end of January(31/01/2014) plus 50 days (x represents the number of days) = 22/03/2014
Serie B: M4 2014 = end of April (30/04/2014) plus 40 days = 09/06/2014
Serie C: M2 2014 = end of February (28/02/2014) plus 57 days = 26/04/2014
Serie D: Q4 2013 = end of December (31/12/2013) plus 25 days = 25/01/2014
```

I've created a dictionary like that is called dico

```
     serie_name latest_release_time available
     serie A    22/03/2014          . 
     serie B    09/06/2014          .
     serie C    26/04/2014          . 
     serie D    25/01/2014          .
```

Let's say that the today's date is 08/07/2014.

My aim would be to select the latest series. In this example, it would be Serie B as it is the closest to the 08/07/2014

I don't think there is a function in SAS or SQL that allows you to check the nearest date except if you say do something like that

```
proc sql;
update dico set available="yes" where intnx('month',release_date,1) > date();
quit;
```

Am I correct?

Cheers for the help.

Comment: Hello, does it make sense? :)

Comment: Not to me.  Suggest you edit the question to remove all the introduction stuff about time series.  Is the question something like: "Given my dico dataset, how can I create a column AVAILABLE which would be set to "Yes" for the row with latest_release_time closest to today's date?"  I think that's an answerable question, if you can say how you would want to handle ties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I THINK you are looking for:

You can use an inner select in SQL.  There are other ways to do it, but this is pretty easy to understand.

```
data test;
x = 0;
format date date9.;
do date = "01JAN2013"d to "31DEC2014"d by 4;
   do i=1 to 3;
      x = x + 1;
      output;
   end;
end;
run; 

proc sql noprint;
create table temp as
select date, i, x
from test
where date = (
    select min(date) from test where date >= today()
);
quit;
```

First, I generate some fake data.  Then I use SQL to get only the first records with the DATE variable that satisfies my criteria (`date >= today()`).

Let us know if this is not what you want.

Comment: Hi Dom, it does work. The min is the only solution. Thank you.